# No module named 'stdio'

Tags: python-3.x, import, directory, pycharm, stdio

I have "stdlib-python" and "guess.py" under the same folder named "Projects". I'm trying to use "import stdio" in guess.py, but when I it or any available modules in "stdlib-python", it red lines the module name and say "No module named '(module name)'". However, let's say if I move the "stdio.py"(from stdlib-python") to "Projects", I am able to use stdio module. Same for the rest of the module. I can only use the modules if I remove them from "stdlib-python" directory. Is there a way to make it work the way it is right now? I'm using PyCharm(Idk if it matters)

Picture: https://gyazo.com/6b4797260c0b470fdeeffc6652bda1ac

Answer (score 0):

First of all change "stdlib-python" to "stdlib_python" then do the following:

```
from stdlib_python import stdio
```

This will only work if `stdlib_python` subdirectory and `guess.py` are in the same directory.